# implement Next Auth login with CredentialsProvider

Tags: javascript, mongoose, next.js, next-auth

I got an issue that when I find the user from the data base and store it into a variable result and but I found that the result get the current user but without the password key so the result.password value is undefined I don't know why if you can help me guys and I saw others on Youtube doing the same thing but the user do come with the password key.

```
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import dbConnect from '../../../lib/dbConnect';
import User from '../../../models/User';
import { compare } from 'bcryptjs';


export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
           name: 'Credentials',
           async authorize(credentials, req) {
               await dbConnect()

               console.log(credentials)

               //check user existance
               const result = await User.findOne({email: credentials.email})

               if(!result){
                   throw new Error('No user Found With Email Please Sign Up!')
               }

               console.log(result) /* the output give me the user back but without the 
                password so result.password is undefind 
                  {
                   _id: new ObjectId("63c6cf0eeed325fcb7d46dbd"),
                   name: 'test user',
                   email: 'example@gmail.com',
                   provider: false,
                   isAdmin: false,
                   createdAt: 2023-01-17T16:38:38.133Z,
                   updatedAt: 2023-01-17T16:38:38.133Z,
                   __v: 0
                  }
                 even though i check the database and i found the user there with a 
                 password
                */

               //compare password
               const checkPassword = await compare(credentials.password, result.password)
               if(!checkPassword || result.email !== credentials.email){
                    throw new Error("Email or Password dosen't match")
               }
            return result
          }
        })
      ],
      database: process.env.DB_URL
   })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is that  Mongoose model User has select: false option set for the password field this means that password field is excluded from the query result by default to fix this you need to pass the select option to the findOne method:

```
 const result = await User.findOne({email:credentials.email}).select('+password')
```